# Electrolysis, Concentration of Electrolytes

Tags: concentration, electrolysis

[image]

So it says the Chlorine gets discharged as the concentration of chlorine ions are higher than OH ions, but why don't the concentration applies to Na+ ??

Comment: The *real* question is why they don't say $\ce{Cl-}$ gets discharged because of its position in the electrochemical series.

Comment: It is not only concentration - the potential is important too.  $\ce{Na+}$ is much harder to reduce than $\ce{H+}$, so despite the concentration, $\ce{H+}$ goes first. $\ce{Cl-}$ are easier to discharge than $\ce{OH-}$, and also more abundant, so the choice is obvious.

Comment: Really? But According to my book, it says OH- has a higher tendency to discharge when compared with Cl-, as shown in this picture..
https://sciencezoneja.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/electrochemical-series.jpg

Comment: $E^\circ(\ce{Cl2}/\ce{Cl-}) = +1.36~\mathrm{V}$ and $E^\circ(\ce{O2}/\ce{OH-}) =  +0.40~\mathrm{V}$. $\ce{OH-}$ is easier to oxidise than $\ce{Cl-}$. I think it is a matter of concentration. Related question: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15435/why-is-chloride-oxidised-instead-of-water-in-copper-chloride-electrolysis Loong mentioned overpotential in that answer.

Comment: @orthocresol It is weird to see someone talk about $E^0$ and mention $\ce{OH-}$ at the same time … My source says $E^0 (\ce{O2}/\ce{H2O}) = 1,23~\mathrm{V}$. Which is rather close to chlorine’s. Remember that standard potentials are measured at pH 0. But you are correct and I was wrong with their order.

Comment: @Jan I agree that $E^\circ(\ce{O_2}/\ce{H2O})$ is much more appropriate. $E^\circ(\ce{O_2}/\ce{OH-})$ (or $E(\ce{O_2}/\ce{OH-})$) is measured at pH 14 which is obviously not the case for a concentrated salt solution.